# When should I use startAt, endAt and when range where?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to query data between two values.
should I use

```
collection
.where("value",">=",'start')
.where("value","<=",'end')
```

or

```
collection
.orderBy('value')
.startAt('start')
.endAt('end')
```

is there any difference at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, for a single query, probably not going to make much difference.  However, using startAt and endAt is typically only used for [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).  So it might be confusing for the reader of your code to see those methods if you aren't actually doing any pagination.  The first example is more clear for single queries.